# Lucene multiple categories facets with one query (facets graph)

Tags: lucene, facet

We have a website with multiple facets (types, codes, colors for simplicity) and we want to show numbers for each category.

Categories are not really hierarchical but we would like to implement (we don't know if it is really wise to do so) a way to show numbers on sub selection without executing a new sub query that uses a filter with the selection.

Let's do an example.
We have in the main page this layout:

```
TYPE
A (20)
B (5)

COLORS 
red (10)
blue(15)

CODES
aa (10) 
bb (15)
```

When we select Type A we now perform a new query to obtain the facets of the new configuration es:

```
TYPE
A (20)

COLORS 
red (8)
blue(12)

CODES
aa (6) 
bb (14)
```

Is there a way to use hierarchical facets to get the number of the "virtual sub categories"?

Theorically it would be like defininig facets with `A/red/aa` `A/red/bb`, `A/blue/aa`, `A/blue/bb` if we consider the type as first selection or creating a permutation of possible values to have a generic implementation of it.

Is there an official way to achieve it? Is it better just to create a total new query instead of building this "graph of facets"?